# Find the value of $x$ in the given logarithmic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

$$\text{Solve for $x$}\begin{cases} (x+1)^{\log_{10}(x+1)} &= 100(x+1) \\ 3^{(\log_3x)^2}+x^{\log_3x}&=162\end{cases}$$

Can we take $\log$ both sides but it did not work for me. I am not getting. What other properties can we apply here?

*Note*: Both are different questions.

Comment: Is that one question or two?

Comment: both are different i written at end sir

Comment: @fleablood Just wondering: for something like $(\sin x)^2$, this is also written as $\sin^2 x$. Can the same be done for $(\log x)^2$?…… Oh, they can. I just saw a post titled *derivative of $\ \log^k x$*. Nvm

Comment: It's ambiguous and should be avoided.  You will find people writing $(\log x)^2$ as $\log^2 2$ and writing $\frac {d(\frac {d(\log x)}{dx}}{dx}$ as $\log^2 x$.  It should be clear in context what they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x+1)^{log_{10}x+1 } = 100(x+1)$.  Take log of both sides:

$\log_{10} (x+1)^{\log_{10}(x+1)} = \log_10 100(x+1)$

$\log_{10}(x+1)*\log_{10}(x+1) = \log_{10} 100 + \log_{10}(x+1)$.

$\log_{10}^2(x+1) = 2 + \log_{10}(x+1)$

$\log_{10}^2(x+1)-\log_{10}(x+1)-2 = 0$

....

$3^{(\log_3x)^2}+x^{\log_3x}=162$

$3^{\log_3x*\log_3x} + x^{\log_3 x} = 162$

$(3^{\log_3x})^{\log_3 x} + x^{\log_3 x} = 162$

$x^{\log_3x} + x^{\log_3x} = 162$.

Comment: thanks bhai .........

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{\log_3x}=\left(3^{\log_3x}\right)^{\log_3x}=3^{\log_3^2x}.$$

Thus, the second equation gives $$2\cdot3^{\log_3^2x}=162$$ or
$$3^{\log_3^2x}=3^4$$  or
$$\log_3^2x=4,$$ which gives $x=9$ or $x=\frac{1}{9}.$

Comment: thanku sir you always help :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: ok so i stuck  dont now sir hou you got this equation

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: yyup thanku again  , good trick  will help me further

Comment: i think after that x =6  not 9 ?

Comment: $\log_3x=2$ gives $x=9$.

Comment: what is happening with me god knows ,  yes  that was silly mistake by me